# Add conditional to window function

Tags: sql, hive

I have data of the following form:

```
page_name   user_id   date_time             input_age   result_age
Page 1      1420356   2017-11-29 09:25:49   65  
Page 1      1516923   2017-11-29 10:47:15               65
Page 1      1518546   2017-11-29 13:16:34   65  
Page 1      1518546   2017-11-29 13:21:26               78
Page 1      1503723   2017-11-29 10:41:57   59  
Page 1      1503723   2017-11-29 10:46:34               59
Page 1      1761217   2017-11-29 15:59:16   65  
Page 1      1761217   2017-11-29 16:01:59   72  
Page 1      1761217   2017-11-29 16:05:59               67
Page 1      1943018   2017-11-29 11:27:14   65
Page 1      1943018   2017-11-29 11:29:52   67
Page 1      2421391   2017-11-29 09:40:41   63  
Page 1      2421391   2017-11-29 09:45:24               63
Page 1      2421391   2017-11-29 09:51:06               59
Page 1      2421391   2017-11-29 10:14:51   63          59
Page 1      2425813   2017-11-29 10:24:26               60
Page 1      2425813   2017-11-29 10:29:14               59
```

*Note that data is for more than 1 day and there are multiple pages.

What I am looking for is the age that is found based on the latest date_time at the user_id level per page_name; if at that time result_age is not null- take that value (no matter if input_age is null or not). If null, then take input_age value.
So the resulting age is unique at the user_id/page name level, regardless of time.

I know we need something like `row_number() over (partition by user_id, page_name order by date_time desc) as row` ... `where row=1`, but I am not sure how to add the conditional.

Sample output:

```
page_name   user_id   date_time             input_age   result_age
Page 1      1420356   2017-11-29 09:25:49   65  
Page 1      1516923   2017-11-29 10:47:15               65
Page 1      1518546   2017-11-29 13:21:26               78
Page 1      1503723   2017-11-29 10:46:34               59
Page 1      1761217   2017-11-29 16:05:59               67
Page 1      1943018   2017-11-29 11:29:52   67
Page 1      2421391   2017-11-29 10:14:51               59
Page 1      2425813   2017-11-29 10:29:14               59
```

Thank you for the help!

Note that my data is in Hive, but I am assuming it is similar context to most of SQL versions.

Comment: Yes, please put sample output!

Comment: Sure! I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a window function to "get the latest record per x" you generally put your query, including the window function, in a subquery and then put the conditional in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY whatever ORDER BY whateveresle) as rown
  FROM
    joins etc
)a
WHERE 
  rown = 1
```

If you have a couple of dates, and you want one of them, unless it's null in which case you want the other one, use `COALESCE(result_age, input_age)` - gives you result_age if it has a value, otherwise input age. COALESCE takes any number of arguments and works from left to right, giving you back the first one that isn't null

Ultimately, I think the query you've after will be:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(a.result_age, a.input_age) as some_age FROM
(
  SELECT 
    table.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY page_name, user_id ORDER BY date_time DESC) as rown
  FROM
    table
)a
WHERE 
  rown = 1
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, this works exactly as I wanted it.